# Accessing a computer behind a router from the Internet

Tags: networking, router

I have a manufacturing machine that uses PLC's. One of the PLC's needs to have programming updated. PLS'c are updated using proprietary software sold by the PLC maker. In this case the software is $2,000. The tech support person at the machine maker in the past at other facilities has connected directly through the Internet to the PC on the machine and downloaded the programming changes over the Internet. That won't work in our case. All our internal PC's are using IP addesses like 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.0.255.

Teamviewer will not work either. To make Teamviewer work we need the $2,000 software installed on the PC on our end.

The remote programmer won't do the operation using noip.com or similar service.

This is an issue we have from time to time on other pieces of equipment with computers driving them.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You reason for Teamviewer not working does not make sense.  If you are running Teamviewer, then you would be able to run the software on the manufacturing machine ( host ) itself not on the client machine.

Comment: To make Teamviewer work we need the $2,000 software installed on the PC on the manufacturer PC.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple NAT problem to me. Setup your PC as DMZ before the upgrade and give the IP address to the tech support. Upgrade your PLC. Move the PC out of DMZ after upgrade.

Comment: Making the PLC a DMZ is a high risk approach, as someone will probably forget to turn that off. In which case the whole world can have a go at hacking it. If it's just once then OK, but not on a regular basis. 

Basically, if this firm requires an 'open-door' security policy to do support, then you should question that situation.

Comment: I agree. This could all due to incompetence of the tech support personnel not knowing a better alternative.